# How to add the length of the figure?

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I type in different equations and would be glad to know, if one can add a variable length in the line.
This is my minimal code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item $\forall a,b,c, \in \mathbb{R} : \qquad a \le b \Rightarrow  a+c  \le b + c$
\item $\forall a,b,c, \in \mathbb{R} : \qquad a \le b \Rightarrow 
\begin{cases}
a \cdot c \le b \cdot c \ \text{falls} \ c \ge 0 \\
a \cdot c \ge b \cdot c \ \text{falls} \ c \le 0 
\end{cases}
$
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

that results in

[image: Output]

Now I would like to tell LaTeX:

"LaTeX, as I want the lines be nicely aligned horizontally in the list here, take the height (here: horizontal space between the left pick and the right endings) of the brace in the second item and add me the space of the same length before `a+c` in the first item".

So, I just want the space to follow the bracket width. Are such things possible in LaTeX?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do you want to add horizontal space between `\Rightarrow` and `a+c`, equivalent to the width of the brace?

Comment: You can use `\vphantom{\begin{cases} ... \end{cases}}` just before `a+c`...

Comment: In this case yes, this is the horizontal width of the brace.

Comment: @Werner, I liked the idea, but am not sure that it works... I tried it.

Comment: @Kirill: Your actual question should be about *horizontal* alignment, not *vertical*.

Comment: @Werner, thank you for the correction! It originally was, but somebody had edited it before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\hphantom` is the right track. However, the full size of an empty environment `cases` will not work, because it also adds space between the two columns, which are separated by `\quad` (this space should go before "falls"). And at the end, TeX adds the space `\nulldelimiterspace` of the matching `\right.` that closes `\left\lbrace`. The full definition of `cases` in package `amsmath`:

```
\renewenvironment{cases}{%
  \matrix@check\cases\env@cases
}{%
  \endarray\right.%
}
\def\env@cases{%
  \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
  \left\lbrace
  \def\arraystretch{1.2}%
  \array{@{}l@{\quad}l@{}}%
}
```

The following example defines `\HPhantomLeftCases` to simulate the space for the left brace of the environment `cases`. It takes an argument, where the lines with the largest elements of the lines go to get the right size of the left brace.

Additionally, the example further vertically aligns variables `a`, `b`, and `c` by increasing the space for the `\cdot` to take the horizontal space of the plus sign.

BTW, the example uses `\colon`, which behaves as punctuation character rather than a relational operator as `:` does.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath}

\newcommand*{\HPhantomLeftCases}[1]{%
  \hphantom{%
    \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.2}%
    \left\lbrace
    \vphantom{\begin{array}{@{}l@{}}#1\end{array}}%
    \right.%
    \kern-\nulldelimiterspace
  }%
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\WideCDot}{%
  \mathbin{\mathpalette\@WideCDot{}}%
}
\newcommand*{\@WideCDot}[2]{%
  % #1: math style
  % #2: unused
  \sbox0{$#1+\m@th$}%
  \hbox to \wd0{\hfil$#1\cdot\m@th$\hfil}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item $\forall a,b,c, \in \mathbb{R}\colon \qquad a \le b \Rightarrow
\HPhantomLeftCases{a\\b}
a+c  \le b + c$
\item $\forall a,b,c, \in \mathbb{R}\colon \qquad a \le b \Rightarrow 
\begin{cases}
a \WideCDot c \le b \WideCDot c & \text{falls} \ c \ge 0 \\
a \WideCDot c \ge b \WideCDot c & \text{falls} \ c \le 0 
\end{cases}
$
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Of course, the vertical alignments are quite exaggerated (IMHO, I do not see a need to add the phantom space for the left cases brace). But, the example shows, how it can be done, and gives a choice.

Comment: Thank you, @Heiko Oberdiek, that is a really nice one! Vertically alignment looks awesome, true! I will work throough your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Looks like `\hphantom{\Bigg\{}` might do the trick.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item $\forall a,b,c, \in \mathbb{R} : \qquad a \le b \Rightarrow \hphantom{\Bigg\{}  a+c  \le b + c$
\item $\forall a,b,c, \in \mathbb{R} : \qquad a \le b \Rightarrow 
\begin{cases}
a \cdot c \le b \cdot c \ \text{falls} \ c \ge 0 \\
a \cdot c \ge b \cdot c \ \text{falls} \ c \le 0 
\end{cases}
$
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, it really nicely does! Thank you for this particular issue. But can I programm the space?  There is surely a specificator in the LaTeX code that says: "curly brackets have the width/height x". In this particular question it was necessary to insert a space equal to the brace. We've entered the brace. But can we tell Latex to enter the length `n` of some figure somewhere as `n`, `2n`, `3/4n \sin{\pi^2}` and so on?  Thanks again!

Comment: @Kirill Braces can have different width depending on their size.

Comment: @egreg, I propose. But still, "Latex, draw the brace and store it length `x` in the buffer. By the next compilation add me the space of the width x in a particular place." should be possible. As we can use expressions like "`[width=0.3\textlength]`" for figures, expressions like e.g. `\hspace{2\braceheight}` or `\ruleheight=2\textheights` should exists. These are all boxes still.

Answer (score 2):

You decide if you really need this.

I define a `cases+` environment that behaves like `cases`, but stores the width of the brace in the `aux` file for processing in the next LaTeX run.

Each `cases+` environment must have a label that is used in the corresponding `\phantombrace` command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\usepackage{environ}

\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{cases+}[1]{%
  \sbox\z@{% measure the cases without the brace
    \def\lbrace{.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace}%
    $\begin{cases}\BODY\end{cases}$%
  }%
  \sbox\tw@{$\begin{cases}\BODY\end{cases}$}%
  \protected@write\@auxout{}{\string\caseswidthstore{#1}{\the\dimexpr\wd\tw@-\wd\z@}}%
  \begin{cases}\BODY\end{cases}
}
\newcommand{\caseswidthstore}[2]{%
  \expandafter\xdef\csname cws@@#1\endcsname{#2}%
}
\newcommand{\phantombrace}[1]{%
  \kern\@ifundefined{cws@@#1}{0pt}{\@nameuse{cws@@#1}}\relax
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Two line \texttt{cases}
\begin{itemize}
\item $\forall a,b,c, \in \mathbb{R} : \qquad a \le b \Rightarrow 
  \phantombrace{foo2} a+c  \le b + c$
\item $\forall a,b,c, \in \mathbb{R} : \qquad a \le b \Rightarrow 
  \begin{cases+}{foo2}
  a \cdot c \le b \cdot c \ \text{falls} \ c \ge 0 \\
  a \cdot c \ge b \cdot c \ \text{falls} \ c \le 0 
  \end{cases+}
  $
\end{itemize}

Five line \texttt{cases}
\begin{itemize}
\item $\forall a,b,c, \in \mathbb{R} : \qquad a \le b \Rightarrow 
  \phantombrace{foo5} a+c  \le b + c$
\item $\forall a,b,c, \in \mathbb{R} : \qquad a \le b \Rightarrow 
  \begin{cases+}{foo5}
  a \cdot c \le b \cdot c \ \text{falls} \ c \ge 0 \\
  a \cdot c \le b \cdot c \ \text{falls} \ c \ge 0 \\
  a \cdot c \le b \cdot c \ \text{falls} \ c \ge 0 \\
  a \cdot c \le b \cdot c \ \text{falls} \ c \ge 0 \\
  a \cdot c \ge b \cdot c \ \text{falls} \ c \le 0 
  \end{cases+}
  $
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

The code in the `.aux` file reads

```
\caseswidthstore{foo2}{8.05559pt}
\caseswidthstore{foo5}{8.8889pt}
```

so you see that indeed the two braces have different widths.

[image]